# Firebase Firestore collection get method causing error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called 'users' in Firestore, and it is structured like this

users
->
document
-> email, name

```js
db.collection('users').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc)
  });
});
```

This code is supposed to fetch all the documents in the collection (there are about 15), but when I run it, I get a long error (below)

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot {
  _firestore: Firestore {
    _delegate: Firestore$1 {
      type: 'firestore',
      _persistenceKey: '[DEFAULT]',
      _settings: [FirestoreSettingsImpl],
      _settingsFrozen: true,
      _app: [FirebaseAppImpl],
      _databaseId: [DatabaseId],
      _credentials: [FirebaseCredentialsProvider],
      _queue: [AsyncQueueImpl],
      _firestoreClient: [FirestoreClient]
    },
    _persistenceProvider: IndexedDbPersistenceProvider {},
    INTERNAL: { delete: [Function: delete] },
    _appCompat: FirebaseAppImpl {
      firebase_: [Object],
      isDeleted_: false,
      name_: '[DEFAULT]',
      automaticDataCollectionEnabled_: false,
      options_: [Object],
      container: [ComponentContainer]
    }
  },
  _delegate: QueryDocumentSnapshot$1 {
    _firestore: Firestore$1 {
      type: 'firestore',
      _persistenceKey: '[DEFAULT]',
      _settings: [FirestoreSettingsImpl],
      _settingsFrozen: true,
      _app: [FirebaseAppImpl],
      _databaseId: [DatabaseId],
      _credentials: [FirebaseCredentialsProvider],
      _queue: [AsyncQueueImpl],
      _firestoreClient: [FirestoreClient]
    },
```

How should I fetch documents properly without this error?

Firebase version - 8.2.3

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error: With your code you are actually printing the [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) Objects in your console.

You should call the [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#data) method to get the documents data, as follows:

```
db.collection('users').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.data());  // Or console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data())); 
  });
});
```

---

Also note that a `QuerySnapshot` has a [`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) method and therefore you could do:

```
db.collection('users').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
});
```